# Let f: I → ℝ be a function where I is an open interval of ℝ, let a,b∈ℝ with a<b, i have to suppose that f has third derivative

Tags: real-analysis

and also that $f'(a)=f'(b)=f(a)=f(b)=0$, i have to prove that $f^{(3)}(c)=0$ for some $c\in (a,b)$.
i think that i can use the Taylor's theorem for $n=3$, but i found a term that is not canceled for $f^{(3)}(c)$ must be zero.

Comment: Will probably need to assume $f^{(3)}$ exists everywhere on $(a,b)$ - otherwise $f(x) = \min((x-a)^3, (b-x)^3)$ would give a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

By Rolle's Theorem there is $\alpha\in(a,b)$ s.t. $f'(\alpha)=0$, so we have at least three zeros of the derivative. Then use Rolle's theorem twice: once for $f'$ on $[a,\alpha]$ and $[\alpha,b]$, then for $f''$ on some other subinterval.

Comment: Not the OP, but just a passing question: doesn't Rolle's Theorem require continuity - how do we know that $f$, $f'$ and $f''$ are both continuous?

Comment: @Physics Differentiability implies continuity.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Yes, but all he says is that there is a third derivative. He doesn't say that $f$ is differentiable everywhere, which was my point, as Daniel pointed out in the comments in the OP after I posted... But I presume this is what the OP meant.