# $f(a)=f'(a)=f(b)=f'(b)=0$ Prove that there exists $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f'''(c)=0$

Tags: calculus

Let $a<b$ and let $f$ be a function which is three-time differentiable on $[a,b]$. If at the end-points of the interval we have $$f(a)=f'(a)=f(b)=f'(b)=0,$$
prove that there exists $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f'''(c)=0.$

Although I know that $f'(c_1)=0$ and $f''(c_2)=0$, I have no idea how to link them up.

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you see a way of finding *two* points $c_2, c_2'$ such that $f''(c_2) = f''(c_2') = 0$?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2296935/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using Rolle's theorem several times.

$\textbf{1)}$ As $f(a)=f(b)=0$ then exists $c_1 \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c_1)=0$.

$\textbf{2)}$ As $f'(a)=f'(c_1)=0$, exists $c_2 \in (a,c_1)$ such that $f''(c_2)=0$. On the other hand, as $f'(c_1)=f'(b)=0$ then exists $c_3 \in (c_1,b)$ such taht $f''(c_3)=0$. Look that as $c_2 \in (a,c_1)$ and $c_3 \in (c_1,b)$ then $c_2 \neq c_3$ and therefore the interval $(c_2,c_3)$ isn't empty.

$\textbf{3)}$ Finally, as $f''(c_2)=f''(c_3)=0$, then exists $c \in (c_2,c_3)$ such that $f'''(c)=0$.

---

Edit: As mentioned in the comments: As $c_2$ and $c_3$ are points in $(a,b)$ then $c \in (c_2,c_3) \subset (a,b)$.

Comment: One more point....$(c_2,c_3)$ is a subset of $(a,b)$